# ¿ruta php no se actualiza?

Tags: php

tengo una img en mi index.php que tiene lasiguiente ruta en mi directorio

[image: imagen de la estructura de la ruta]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
, en donde hay una imagen, la cuestion es que al actualizar la imagen en esa ruta por medio  del envio de un formulario, php no procesa la nueva imagen para mostrarla, sino que se queda con la anterior.
cabe mencionar que la imagen se carga bien en dirctorio al momento de guardarla en la carpeta dir/img/ , sin embargo php no muestra la imagen actualizada.

Comment: La imagen que actualizas y la que ya estaba tienen el mismo nombre? La reemplazas?

Comment: si excato tienen el mismo nombre,  de manera que cuando subo una, esa imagen pisa a la otra y la actualiza, pero php no la muestra , solo la anterior, ademas estoy trabajando en localhost con un servidor apeche, y cada evz que apago el pc, ahi si muestra la imagen actualizada

Comment: [Mira las respuestas de acá](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137934/how-to-clear-browser-cache-when-re-uploading-image-with-same-filename-in-php), básicamente engañas al browser que es un nueva imagen agregando una variable al final, lo mismo se suele hacer con los archivos css para que el browser piense que es uno nuevo